# How do I show code snippets in a tabbed panel in Jekyll?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I'm writing a blog which will feature code snippets.
These code snippets are translated into three or four different languages. I want to show these in a [tabbed panel in twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

I have bootstrap installed, but I don't know how to create this custom widget.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this ?

Comment: Hi @HansSjunnesson. Just curious as I am looking for a solution myself. Any more luck so far?

Comment: No such luck :(